# OrderBy with lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, foreach

I have following function to generate a table shown in the output screenshot. I want to modify this function to get desired output shown below but I am not very familiar with C#. If I pass years array into this function that consists of 3 items, how should I modify this function?

```
        private string GenerateHTML(string year)
        {
            var regions = RegionalList(year);
            if (!regions.Any()) return "";

            var rowHtmlString = regions.OrderByDescending(row => row.Capacity).Aggregate("", (current, row) => current + $@"
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <p>{row.Region}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <p>{row.Percent.ToString("F1")}%</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            ");
        return rowHtmlString;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Using Aggregate to build HTML.. oof. You need to have your other years present in the object, and maybe make Percent an array.. The problem goes deeper though because youre crosstabbing with data in the headers that changes (sometimes it'll be 2023, 2022, 2021 ? ) so you need to also have your headers in the data item otherwise you'll have to recompile your app next year.. Have your percents in an array e.g. `row.Percents[0]` for 2022, `row.Percents[1]` for 2021 etc.. and eg a first `row.Headers = new string[] { "2022","2021", "2020" }` that defines what [0], [1], [2] etc actually mean..

Comment: Also, you don't need to `$"some data {x.MyFloat.ToString("F1")}..."` , you can just  `$"some data {x.MyFloat:F1}..."`

Comment: C# is a language of types - what is the type of `regions`? Where in the type is years array? What have you tried?

Comment: You forgot to tell us the return value of method `RegionalList`. Our answer depends heavily upon the contents of object `regions`. Consider to edit your question and describe the class.